# How do I make a class (that already exist) inherit another class?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8

For example class `res.partner`. I want `res.partner` to inherit class `A`. How do I do that?

I don't think this will work:

```
class custom_res_partner(osv.osv):

    _name           = "res.partner"
    _inherit        = "A"

custom_res_partner()
```

Comment: What is your purpose behind to create new model with name which is already exists ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If model is already present and you want it to inherit another model, it should be done like this:

```
class custom_res_partner(osv.osv):
    _name = "res.partner"
    _inherit = ['res.partner', 'A']
```

`_name` part is important here, with it Odoo knows which model inherits from which. in `_inherit` you also need to specify `res.partner`, because you are extending this model.

Answer (score 1):

```
class custom_res_partner(osv.osv):

    _name           = "custom.res.partner"    # New Model will be created
    _inherit        = "A"   # Base class 

custom_res_partner()
```

It will create new model(table) which have all the properties of it's base class according to inheritance rules. Don't use the res.partner because this model is already there.

Comment: I want the `res.partner` to inherit `A`. I don't want to make a new model.

Answer (score 1):

```
# odoo-8
from openerp import fields, models, api, _
class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = "A"
```

**EDIT:**
(This is for odoo version 8)
Create a new module and inherit the model `A` in a python file in the module.
For creating a new module, refer to [Build an Odoo module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html#build-an-odoo-module)

Comment: What if I don't want to edit the original file? I want it to inherit the other model without even touching the original source code.

Comment: I don't think you get my question. I don't want to create a new module. I want to make the preexisting `res.partner` inherit `A` without editing the original source code.

Comment: @William what did you meant by 'without editing the original source code'? You want it to be done from the odoo client.

Comment: Ok for example I have a class named `B` which is written in a file `class_b.py`, and I have a class named `A` which is written in a file `class_a.py`. How do I make `B` to inherit `A` without editing `class_b.py` and making another file called `custom_class_b.py` instead. What do I write in `custom_class_b.py`?